# Compare positions of integers in this sequence

Tags: code-golf, math, decision-problem, integer

[A001057](https://oeis.org/A001057) is one way to represent an integer as a natural number. It lists them according to the following pattern:

```
0, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 4, -4, ...
```

In this challenge, you'll take two distinct integers as input and return which is at a higher index in this enumeration.

Take `-2` and `1` as an example: `-2` comes after `1`, so it would be returned.

You may also choose to instead return the smaller integer, or one of two consistent values (such as `0` or `1`) to indicate which is higher or lower. Truthy/falsy values as output are not allowed.

**Test cases:**

```
 0   1       1
 1   0       1
 0  -1      -1
-1   0      -1
-1   1      -1
 1  -1      -1
 1  -2      -2
 1   2       2
-1  -2      -2
-1   2       2
```

Comment: Can we take input as a list of the two numbers, and then output the list, sorted according to the sequence? e.g. `[-6,4] -> [4,-6]`

Comment: @AaronMiller No, sorry

Comment: "Truthy/falsy values as output are not allowed" is a weird restriction for a lot of languages considering you allow `0`/`1` (basically for all loose type ones): in Javascript or PHP, `0`/`1` are falsey/truthy values, as well as all the numbers in the sequence btw..

Comment: @Kaddath I allow any two distinct outputs, not just `0` and `1`. You could choose to return `true` and `false` if you want, just not any inconsistent truthy/falsy values.

Comment: Makes sense, I think it could be clearer in the post, maybe with "Inconsistent truthy/falsy values as output are not allowed."?

Comment: By "may choose to return the smaller integer," you mean "the integer at a lower index," right?

Comment: @DLosc That's what I meant, yeah

Answer (score 11):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), 20 bytes

```python
lambda x,y:x*x>y*y-y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY0xDoMwEAR7v2LT2chEhFBZOj6SUBARK5YcgxDF3eudS0ExGk01mxyftfQ10rPm@ftaZrCXwA2P0kgrNdOj87h5tEqvUu4qZVANkzFx3cFIBTkY/EPOQIrgC0nY9lQO2HxNZXmzZYcRZ4hzIEK0OnZe95D6Aw)

Checks whether \$x^2>y^2-y \$.

Outputs `True/False` for whether `x` comes after `y` in the listing. Note that we're not asked handle the case `x==y`.

To see that this works, note that each of the `x*x` value in the table is greater than all the `y*y-y` values to the left of it, but none to the right of it.

```python
       0  1  -1  2  -2  3  -3   4  -4 ...
x*x:   0  1   1  4   4  9   9  16  16 ...
y*y-y: 0  0   2  2   6  6  12  12  20 ...
```

The idea is that the entries come in pairs `+n, -n` (except 0 once), so comparing squares works to check if one input has a bigger absolute value than the other. Then, changing \$y^2\$ to \$y^2-y\$ in the second entry, makes `+n` "lose" to `-n`, but is a small enough shift compared to the difference between consecutive squares that it doesn't mess up comparisons between different squares.

Comment: Also 20 but weirder! : lambda x,y:x*x>y*~-y

Answer (score 6):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 8 bytes

```
>&(-3^|)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY0xCsMwEAR7vWJJEUngM5bSCezGkCpVHpArjOWQJg9I/q7IPhtskeJgdxj2XulU64g2QKNCg5CPavT32zV1Z0OXx9cmq6Y2mPiprBqH5xvsEOEkz5GdkqKJSK/Z5KUJcBYUsNkm@xk2BZxNFpM3yDuzgIW5bPJf6AX6w3eB8PvN0uSDmX4)

Or verbose: `(x - 3 ^ abs(x)) > (y - 3 ^ abs(y))`.
This maps the inputs to the following sequence to compare them in:

```
 0  1 _1  2  _2   3  _3   4  _4    5   _5
_1 _2 _4 _7 _11 _24 _30 _77 _85 _238 _248
```

If sorted input as output is allowed, then 7 byte `/:*.@%:` is another fun way to sort `/:` the input list: `*.` generates `(length, angle)` pairs of the square root `%:` of `x` (which results in complex numbers for negative values):

```
 0       0      0
 1       1      0
_1       1 1.5708
 2 1.41421      0
_2 1.41421 1.5708
 3 1.73205      0
_3 1.73205 1.5708
```

Comment: Very nice solution

Answer (score 5):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
F>m€Θİ±
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/380u91HTmnMzjmw4tPH////RuoY6hrEA)

Returns `1` if the second is larger than the first, `0` otherwise

Comment: removing the `Θ` will work since `0` is at the first index anyway

Comment: @Razetime That [hangs forever](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/380u91HTmiMbDm38//9/tK6hjkEsAA) if `0` is in the input

Comment: ah forgot we were using `€`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 21 bytes

```
f(x,y)=\{xx-x<yy,0\}
```

(Newline is required)

*Edit: Just noticed that [xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231851/96039) is very similar to mines, but I found this independently.*

Function is \$f(x,y)\$, and it returns \$0\$ if \$x\$ has a higher index, otherwise returns \$1\$.

This seems to work, but I just randomly stumbled upon it, so I can't explain how it works.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/v7pjc0sebx)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/aa6fqxkom4)

Comment: I don't think this will work for `-1, 1` (or if it does, for `1, -1`)

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
²?Ḣ+⇧
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C2%B2%3F%E1%B8%A2%2B%E2%87%A7&inputs=%5B-1%2C%202%5D&header=&footer=)

Takes input as a list and returns [1,0] for first being bigger, [0,1] for second being bigger.

```
²     # [x^2, y^2]
 ?Ḣ   # [y]
   +  # [x^2+y, y^2]
    ⇧ # Grade up
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 5 bytes

```
²Ḥ_ṠỤ
```

[Try It Online!](https://jht.hyper-neutrino.xyz/tio#WyIiLCLCsuG4pF/huaDhu6QiLCLDh+KCrCIsIiIsWyJbWzAsIDFdLCBbMSwgMF0sIFswLCAtMV0sIFstMSwgMF0sIFsxLCAtMV0sIFsxLCAtMl0sIFsxLCAyXSwgWy0xLCAtMl0sIFstMSwgMl1dIl1d)

-1 byte thanks to ovs
-1 byte thanks to Unrelated String

Returns `[1, 2]` if the first integer comes first and `[2, 1]` for the second integer.

```
²Ḥ_ṠỤ    Main Link; accepts a list
²        x ** 2
 Ḥ       2 * (x ** 2)
   _Ṡ    2 * (x ** 2) - sign(x)
     Ụ   Grade up
```

```
 0 => 0
 1 => 1
-1 => 3
 2 => 7
-2 => 9
 3 => 17
-3 => 19
...
```

Comment: I don't know if this stretches the two consistent values too much, but if you replace `ṢƑ` with `Ụ`, this returns `[1, 2]` / `[2, 1]` for sorted / not sorted

Comment: `×4` \$\to\$ `Ḥ`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/x4Y4l8Q93Lni4c9Gxif8f7tjkc6w97FHTmoc7px3aerjd@eHubq6Hu7ccbgeKRf7/r2CgoKBgqAAGhlxglgGcB2TpQuV0Dbl0kSRhXIQsiKmLxjWCco0gBkO5RmCtSJK6yJIA "Jelly – Try It Online")

Comment: @ovs oh yeah those are two consistent values so i see no problem with that, thanks

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing doesn't work for `-1,2 / 2,-1`

Comment: [`Ḥ` LIVES](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Qpoc7lsQ/3Lng4e4l/w@3P2pa8/9/dLSBjoJhrI5CtKGOggGIBvJ1wQK6MBFDmAiIYQRlGMGU6MJZYIaRDlBtLAA)

Comment: @UnrelatedString ah, very nice

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>29</s> 26 bytes

Returns `True` if `a` is a at a higher index than `b`, `False` otherwise.

```python
lambda a,b:a*a+(a<0)/2>b*b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY1NDoMgEIX3nmI2RKCQIt0Z60XaLiBIamLRAF309BSExcyX9978HL/43t0tWbjDM23qo40CxfSoqLpgNQlylbOmOsUlxJCHHliwgTA8MJG7YLwIXlVGjXiDPCFrxBsleXV291AuwupOhrED8Ev4bjH/sJgWk2Tv8KuLuEfSQCk@AzI9IKgTrO0Qkv4)

Comment: How about `-a==b>0`?

Comment: @pxeger That would've worked ;)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

```
ȧ4*?±-⇧
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C8%A74*%3F%C2%B1-%E2%87%A7&inputs=%5B-1%2C%202%5D&header=&footer=)

Oh yes, jelly port. Very fun.

`⟨0|1⟩` for second integer being yes, `⟨1|0⟩` for first integer being yes.

### Explained

```
ȧ4*?±-⇧
ȧ4*     # 4 * abs(input) [vectorised] # call this x
   ?±   # sign_of(input) [vectorised - <0 = -1, =0 = 0, >0 = 1] # call this y
     -  # x - y [vectorised element-wise] # call this z
      ⇧ # indexes of z in an order such that they would arrange z to be sorted ascending
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
Ḥc2Ụ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjiXJRg93L4Ew/v@PNtAx1NE11DHS0TXSMdbRNdYx0dE1iQUA)

Alternative grade-up solution. Uses `(2n)C2 = n(2n-1)` as the grade key function. This function maps `0, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, ...` to `0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, ...`, i.e. the triangular numbers.

This allows a shorter APL solution:

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 5 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
⍋2!+⍨
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=e9TbbaSo/ah3BQA&f=S1MwUDDkSlMwVDi0HkQDSSBfw0hR@1HvCk2QJFjICEgaKRgDSWMFEyBpAgA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=train&n=f)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 5 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Outputs `true` for the first number being higher or `false` for the second.

```
²+V>²
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=sitWPrI&input=LTEKMg)

Answer (score 2):

## [COW](https://bigzaphod.github.io/COW/), 183 bytes

```
oomMMMmoOMMMmoOoomMMMmoOMMMmOomOoMMMmoOmoOmoOMMMMMMmoOMMMmOomOoMMMmoOmoOmoOMMMMMMmoOMMMmOoMOOmOomOomOomOomOomOoMOOMOomoOmoOMOOMoOmoOmoOMOOMoOmoOmoOMOoMMMOOOmooOOOmooOOOmooMMMmoomoOOOM
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jUyxDcAwDNp7TXsI4ojOEWPOd0iQqmSrhSywgVe9SmoAmph9SMqIDLDm5xdkPDt8hEn85l/24LOWjkv7XuUza2/VfT0D)

Returns the smaller integer.
It increases and decreases both, the first to reach **0** (with precedence to the decreasing one) is the smaller.

```
[0]: n to be decreased   [1]: n   [2]: m to be increased   [3]: m   [4]: n to be increased   [5]: n   [6]: m to be decreased   [7]: m

i=>=>i=>=<<=>>>==>=<<=>>>==>=<    | set up memory cells as above
[                                 | loop until a cell reaches 0
    <<<<<<[->>[+>>[+>>-=*]*]*]=   | [0]-- [2]++ [4]++ [6]--
]>o                               | print the redundant copy of the smaller

moo ]    mOo <    MOo -    OOO *    OOM i
MOO [    moO >    MoO +    MMM =    oom o
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ), 30 bytes

```
lambda x,y:(x*x,x<0)>(y*y,y<0)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728oLIkIz_PaMHiNNuYpaUlaboW-3ISc5NSEhUqdCqtNCq0KnQqbAw07TQqtSp1KoEsiKKbzuUZmTmpCoZWQGU6SbaZeQWlJRqa1gVFmXkl0Up5-Uo6SvnZSrHRaRpABZq2thoVtrZJmrE6YOU6EFGIUQtuehroGOoYchnqAGkuAx1dQyDi0gVxITSYbwgVBxJGQASkjXSMQLIQri6YDzERAA)

This is one of those irritating ones that can't be shortened with a loop because the loop is only over 2 items.

The `abs(x)` -> `x*x` trick was taken from ovs' answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 19 bytes

```
Most@*SortBy[-# #&]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773ze/uMRBKzi/qMSpMlpXWUFZLfZ/QFFmXomCvkO6vkN1tYGOYa1OtaGOAZA00NEFcXQhPCAFkdKFUkZgyggipQuljWpr//8HAA)

-23 bytes from @att

Comment: [19 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773ze/uMRBKzi/qMSpMlpXWUFZLfZ/QFFmXomCvkO6vkN1tYGOYa1OtaGOAZA00NEFcXQhPCAFkdKFUkZgyggipQuljWpr//8HAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

A port of [hyper-neutrino's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231845/64121). Outputs are swapped.

```apl
⍋×-4×|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1Fv9@HpuiaHp9f8T3vUNuFRb9@jvqme/o@6mg@tN37UNhHICw5yBpIhHp7B/9MVgGoUqoGyj3q3Rj/qnQfkpikA2bG1XBrpCgoGCgqGmgq2QBLMNQSKIHENFA6tB0sDKZAAkIIqQBZAVgE0AVULWMAIImAEswPMVzCCmYCqAGwmVAUA) `g` gets the *"higher"* number according to the output.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 20 bytes

```c
f(a,b){a=a*a>b*b-b;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZHBToQwEIbv@xQjySaFbSOL8WCQvRifQohpS1mJym4KiUTCq4tToBU2HpZk0mH@@f6hg2RHKYehIJwKv@MJD/hBBIKJuB/KqoFPXlbEh24D@JhCo@rmlb9kkGChCynsKQAebD8FLGKq9fEaFhZGdQbN6YAI88ieC1i1ZyUblY/4YrKbGF7GHxyAfFPyXekJ9tL2OUrbhyeMe4/C8v3Om7HipIGYwWWVqxaxMJ7TR6jLb3UqiP0k/3YuBK4Sw243dtvl2WtwdJqXOOpZvJKFlcW/skbZ/CwQ/lpQKLgNXZJnjS0F8bZRDibYAbaY1WmFlzdmFDR1K9JJorKF/TQTe7h/paUYXdeWN86z3/TDjyw@@LEe2Ncv)

Port of [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor)'s [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231851/9481).

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 37 bytes

```scala
_.maxBy(x=>if(x>0)x*2-1 else x.abs*2)
```

[Try it online!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ylWvG2RwRJ2SJUQJ2fi04A)

Very simple, simply takes a list containing the two number, maps each to its index in the sequence, and finds the max according to that.

Comment: 33 bytes: `_.maxBy(x=>if(x>0)x*2-1 else-x*2)`. Porting my answer gives `_.maxBy(x=>2*x*x-x)` for 19 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
²+ḊỤ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///QJu2HO7oe7l7y/3D7o6Y1//9HRxvoKBjG6ihEG@ooGIBoIF8XLKALEzGEiYAYRlCGEUyJLpwFZhjpANXGAgA)

<s>Terrible</s> port of xnor's Python solution, also stealing from hyper-neutrino's Jelly solution ovs's output format (`[1, 2]` if `y` is greater, `[2, 1]` if `x` is greater). Takes input as a list `[x, y]`.

```
²       [x^2, y^2]
 +      plus
  Ḋ     [y]:
²+Ḋ     [x^2 + y, y^2].
   Ụ    Grade up.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 10 bytes

```
Ｉ⌊Φθ⁼↔ι⌈↔θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzczLzO3NFfDLTOnJLVIo1BHwbWwNDGnWMMxqTg/p7QkVSNTU0fBN7ECrAouWKgJAdb//0dH6xrrKBjHxv7XLcsBAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a list of two (actually arbitrary many) integers (which need not be distinct). Explanation: Outputs the element with the greatest absolute value, or the less of two elements tied for absolute value. Explanation:

```
   θ        Input list
  Φ         Filter where
      ι     Current element
     ↔      Absolute value
    ⁼       Equals
         θ  Input list
        ↔   Vectorised absolute value
       ⌈    Take the maximum
 ⌊          Take the minimum
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implicitly print
```

Actually a port of @xnor's Python answer would probably be only 9 bytes but that would be boring.

Answer (score 0):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 14 bytes

```
f:{x*x>-y+y*y}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qukKrwk63UrtSq7L2f5qCgbXhfwA)

Comment: If you intended to port `a*a>b*b-b`, your current code is totally wrong since it is `x*(x>-(y+y*y))` now. The easiest way to fix it is to parenthesize like `{(x*x)>(y*y)-y}`. Btw, you can exclude `f:` from byte count.